# SQL server - Difference between Natively Compiled Stored Procedure and ordinary stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, compiled

As always I used to create ordinary stored procedures regarding the second option for creating stored procedure called "`Natively Compiled Stored Procedure`" I wanna know if there is any performance benefit to using compiled one?

Is there anyone can Help to find out?
Thanks

Comment: Why down vote? Please leave a comment after down voting

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I the documentation link that answers your question is the first result in the google search https://www.google.com/#q=Natively+Compiled+Stored+Procedure

Comment: Could someone please explain it better? Why and when someone should use natively compiled stored procedures?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stored procedures that are marked with `NATIVE_COMPILATION` are natively compiled. This means the Transact-SQL statements in the procedure are all compiled to native code **for efficient execution of performance-critical business logic.**

For more information, see [Native Compilation of Tables and Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/native-compilation-of-tables-and-stored-procedures)